# Documents or Tutorials about android.graphics.Camera and android.graphics.Matrix?

Tags: android, 3d, matrix, camera, android-canvas

I know that it may be seems as **not constructive** or **off topic** question.But I ask this question after I searched more than 40 or 50 times in Google to find a good documents or tutorials in about [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) and [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html).

I have to do 3D animation in Android by `Canvas`,`Camera`,`Matrix` and without `Open GL`.

Finally I found some examples,but they have a little description in about methods and differences between them.([Touch Controlled Cube on Samsung Galaxy S2](http://codentronix.com/2011/10/08/first-android-app-touch-controlled-cube-on-samsung-galaxy-s2/) or [Making your own 3D list](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/31/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-2/)).Now with no documents,every things looks like magic and I can not debug my project.

So I asked my question here:
***Do you know a good tutorial or document in about using `Canvas`,`Camera`,`Matrix` for 3D animation?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally,after some days,best resource that I found is:

[Understanding Animation](http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2898)

But it is not complete resource.

Answer (score -1):

For the basics you can try [the new boston tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6)